# How to call stored procedures Mysql in SPRING DATA JPA

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I read How to call  mysql stored procedures in JPA

[call-stored-procedures-jpa](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/)

but my procedure api no out put parament !

How to call it  and return result in spring data jpa

```
CREATE DEFINER=`tester`@`%` PROCEDURE `GET_TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY` (in a_id_term integer unsigned)
BEGIN
declare v_trn_key bigint unsigned;
    set v_trn_key = null;
    start transaction;
    select seq from TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY where id_term = a_id_term into v_trn_key for update;
    if v_trn_key is null then
        set v_trn_key = 1;
        insert into TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY(id_term,seq) values(a_id_term,v_trn_key);
    else
        set v_trn_key = v_trn_key + 1;
        update TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY set seq = v_trn_key where id_term = a_id_term;
    end if;
    commit;
    select v_trn_key;
END$$
```

Java Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
   @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getNextTransactionKeyByTerminalId", 
                              procedureName = "GET_TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY",
//                              resultClasses = {Object.class},
                              parameters = {
                                 @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "a_id_term", type = Long.class)
                              })
})

public class TerminalTransactionKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_term" ,unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int idTerm;
    @Column(name = "seq")
    private BigInteger seq;

    public TerminalTransactionKey() {
    }

    public TerminalTransactionKey(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

my repo

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;



public interface TerminalTransactionKeyRepository extends  CrudRepository<TerminalTransactionKey, Long>{


    @Procedure(name = "getNextTransactionKeyByTerminalId")
    Long nextIdByTerminalId(@Param("a_id_term") Long terminalId);

    @Query("UPDATE TerminalTransactionKey SET seq=:nextExtTrnId WHERE idTerm=:terminalId")
    int updateSequence(@Param("nextExtTrnId")Long nextExtTrnId, @Param("terminalId") Long terminalId);

}
```

and my test

```
@Test
public void testNextId() {
    log.info(repository.nextIdByTerminalId(1L));

}
```

out p6spy call is ok! but in log

> 16:26:30 [INFO ] [main] [] []
>   LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:Initialized JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'PersistanceUnitTest'
>   16:26:31 [INFO ] [main] [] [] p6spy:1490189191865|connectionId
>   2|elapsed 118|category statement
>       {call GET_TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY(1)} Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.18 sec <<< FAILURE! - in
>   ru.service.TerminalTransactionKeyServiceImplTest
>   testNextId(ru.service.TerminalTransactionKeyServiceImplTest)
>   Time elapsed: 0.47 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   o**rg.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Invalid
>   mix of named and positional parameters; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid mix of named and
>   positional parameters**

Answer (score 0):

best solution

```
@Override
public Long nextIdByTerminalId(Long terminalId) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("CALL GET_TERMINAL_TRANSACTION_KEY(?)", new Object[]{terminalId}, Long.class);
}
```