# ResultSet in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In JDBC after executing the store procedure we will be getting `ResultSet`, so i was wondering how can i achieve the same using Spring Data JPA?

I am having a `Entity` something like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "MyTable.in_and_out_test", procedureName = "in_and_out_test", parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "XML", type = String.class)})
public class MyTable implements java.io.Serializable {
```

....
}

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953195/how-to-call-stored-procedures-mysql-in-spring-data-jpa) question.

Answer (score 2):

Main benefit of using ORM is to avoid mapping between your objects and rows in tables in database (at least in most cases that work out of box with properly annotated entity classes) , so I if I understand correctly what are you asking, than I have to say that I do not see any point in your question.

I suggest to explore a little bit more Spring Data JPA which use Hibernate as implementation by default and to learn how to use benefits of that Spring project.

Comment: This is generally true but OP is calling a stored proc and needs the ResultSet, probably to pull metadata. This is not available with JPA.